# WMI is very slow

Tags: wmi, windows-server-2012-r2, visualsvn-server, wmi-query, wmi-service

We have installed VisualSVN server 3.5 on windows server 2012 r2. When we browsing the repository in the VisualSVN Server Manager, WMI provide host process has started and it uses the very very less cpu usage(4%) even overall CPU usage is less(20%). This means WMI is very slow in background.

we have the script to set the VisualSVN permission using WMI, this WMI query also failed with unknown cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, describe the issue in detail. It is hard to tell what the root cause is from the current issue summary. Checking [VisualSVN Server logs](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/) and Windows Application / System / WMI logs can help.

Note that you can always contact support@visualsvn.com for assistance.

> we have the script to set the Visual SVN permission using WMI, this
>   WMI query also failed with unknown cause.

Try the `*-SvnAccessRule` PowerShell cmdlets such as `Get-SvnAccessRule`, `Add-SvnAccessRule` and `Set-SvnAccessRule`. The access rule management cmdlets help you automate permission management, perform permission modifications in batch and generate permission reports.

---

**IMPORTANT:** VisualSVN Server 3.5.x release family is [out of support since February 28, 2018](https://www.visualsvn.com/company/news/visualsvn-server-3.5-3.6-end-of-support). 3.5.x release family does not receive patch updates. Please, plan to upgrade your VisualSVN Server instance to the latest version, [VisualSVN Server 3.9](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/). Read the article [KB138: Upgrading to VisualSVN Server 3.9](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00138/) before beginning the upgrade. For the complete list of changes between version 3.5 and 3.9, take a look at the [changelog](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think it is looking like system problem. I will check on the system settings..